# $(f^{-1})'(w)$ for a biholomorphic $f$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $U$ and $V$ be open sets containing $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f : U \rightarrow V$ is a biholomorphism. $f (0) = 0$. Then show that for every
$r > 0$ such that $D(0, r) \subset U$ there exists $\rho > 0$ such that for every $w \in D(0, \rho)$
$$(f^{-1})'(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{dD(0,r)}\frac{1}{f(z)-w}dz \ldots (a) $$

My attempt : I know that for a holomorphic injective at $z_0$then there exist $r > 0$ and $\rho > 0$ such that for every $w ∈ D(f (z_0), \rho)$
  $$f^{-1}(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{dD(z_0,r)}\frac{f'(z)z}{f(z)-w}dz $$
Now here we have $f$ is biholomorphic and $f(0)=0$ thus similar to what we do for finding $f'(w)$ for Cauchy's integral formula , I tried on (a) and obtained the following 
$$(f^{-1})'(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{dD(0,r)}\frac{f'(z)z}{(f(z)-w)^2}dz  $$

I am unable to proceed further.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Gamma = \partial D(0,r)$ is the positively oriented circle of radius $r$ around $0$ and $D(0,r) \subset U$, then $f$ maps $\Gamma$ to  a positively oriented simple closed contour $f(\Gamma)$ around $0$.  By Cauchy's integral formula,
applied to the analytic function $(f^{-1})'$, if $w$ is inside $f(\Gamma)$, 
$$ (f^{-1})'(w) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{f(\Gamma)} \dfrac{(f^{-1})'(\zeta)\; d\zeta}{\zeta-w} $$
Now apply the change of variables $z = f^{-1}(\zeta)$, $dz = (f^{-1})'(\zeta)\; d\zeta$, $\zeta  = f(z)$:
$$ (f^{-1})'(w) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma \dfrac{ dz}{ f(z)-w} $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the integrand has a simple pole in $z=f^{-1}(w)$ (why?) and
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{dD(0,r)}\frac{1}{f(z)-w}dz = \text{Res}_{z=f^{-1}(w)}\frac{1}{f(z)-w}=\lim_{z\to f^{-1}(w)}\frac{z - f^{-1}(w)}{f(z)-w}\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks. But I didn’t understand it that well. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @SMath, is simply using the residue formula. And the residue is a limit...